# Sql Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Specific Merchant report in SSRS and it sent out to different merchants everyday at 8am. But the Problem is they want to receive the report only if they have Transactions on it(Contains Data)
They don't want to receive it if the report is empty.

Is there a way to restrict that in SSSRS? Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at data driven subscriptions.  They've been around since SQL Server 2005 and are pretty useful for this kind of thing.  Without knowing more about your scenario, I can't explain exactly how it'll work, but I'm certain it can.  Check out here for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx

Comment: Note that Data Driven Subscriptions are not available in Standard Editions of SQL Server, only Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS subscriptions are pretty basic - either you are subscribed to receive a report or you are not. If you want/need to add logic to that you'll need to roll your own using a console application that you can run as a scheduled task and the reporting services API.

Comment: If you need to create your own and can't use Data Driven Subscriptions, then I recommend looking at using the rs.exe utility to generate reports on demand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839(v=sql.105).aspx